# How should I provide YARD/RDoc documentation for Ruby keyword arguments?

Tags: ruby, documentation, rdoc, yard, keyword-argument

For a basic Ruby method, I would provide YARD style doc for parameters in the following format.

```
# @param query [String] The search string to query.
# @param options [Hash] Optional search preferences.
def search(query, options = {})
  # ...
end
```

With Ruby 2.0, keywords arguments can now be used.  However, I'm not sure how to approach that in terms of the YARD documentation.

```
def search(query, exact_match: false, results_per_page: 10)
  # ...
end
```

How would I document for `exact_match` and `results_per_page` in the second scenario?  Should I just continue to use the `@param` keyword, or is there something better?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Should I just continue to use the @param keyword?

Yes.

---

YARD recognizes keyword arguments. Use `@param` to document a single method parameter (either regular or `keyword`) with a given name, type and optional description:

```ruby
# @param query [String] The search string
# @param exact_match [Boolean] whether to do an exact match
# @param results_per_page [Integer] number of results
def search(query, exact_match: false, results_per_page: 10)
  # ...
end
```

Source: [YARD Tags @param at rubydoc.info](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#param)

Comment: What do you mean "yard recognizes keyword arguments"? The syntax you show is the exact same as non-keyword argument. Does Yard even enforce the contract between params and docstring? And wouldn't it be confusing if a method wanted a keyword arg but is documented as having a regular, sequential argument

Comment: @maxple I haven't touched ruby in awhile, but have you looked at the _rendered output_ of yard for this syntax? I believe there the keyword arguments are rendered differently than sequential arguments...

Comment: @UriAgassi No, the output does not distinguish between regular and keyword arguments.